# Trained model cannot be saved tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I cannot save a trained model in tensorflow

i have fitted data

```
results = model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,epochs=20,validation_data=test_image_gen,callbacks=early_stop)
```

and imported

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

and written a code like this

```
save1= results.history
save1.save('model.h5')
```

but it throws an error like this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-13cfa06fe0cd> in <module>
----> 1 save1.save('model.h5')

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

i can't figure out what to do to save this model please also help me how to save this in yaml file

ps:-i am working on kaggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when saving model in `TensorFlow`. You call the `save` method on the model it's self not on the `history` object returned from `fit or fit_generator`.

Kindly use this

```
  model.save('model.h5')
```